# Shiny - adding sections to an rmarkdown report dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to add a new report section with a new title and a new graph plot each time that the actionButton `printNewPlot` is clicked. How can I do this?

**app.R**

```
library(igraph)

 shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
        actionButton("printNewPlot", "Print new plot to report"),
        downloadButton("report", "Download report")
      ),
      server = function(input, output) {
        output$report <- downloadHandler(
          # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
          filename = "report.html",
          content = function(file) {
            # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
            # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
            # can happen when deployed).
            tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
            file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

            # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
            params <- list(n = input$slider)

            # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
            # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
            # from the code in this app).
            rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
            )
          }
        )
      }
    )
```

**report.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

# I want a new title each time that printNewPlot is clicked

```{r}

plot(make_ring(params$n))
```

# If printNewPlot is clicked again, a new title must appear here

```{r}
#alongside a new plot
plot(make_ring(params$n))
```
````

Comment: I would extend your params to include a variable from the app with the naming convention for the title, and then write an inline R code title for the heading using the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two things: an object to store your list of inputs; and looped printing within your RMD that receives the stored input as a parameter. Note that I didn't have the `make_ring()` function so that through an error.

For the app:

```
server = function(input, output) {

RV <- reactiveValues(Clicks=c())

observeEvent(input$slider, {

  #create object for clicked polygon
  click <- input$slider
  RV$Clicks <-c(RV$Clicks,click)
  print(unique(RV$Clicks))

})

output$report <- downloadHandler(
  # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
  filename = "report.html",
  content = function(file) {
    # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
    # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
    # can happen when deployed).
    tempReport <- file.path( "report.Rmd")
    #file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
    params <- list(n = RV$Clicks)

    # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
    # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
    # from the code in this app).
    rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                      params = params,
                      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
    )
  }
)
```

}
)

For the RMD file

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n:  NA
---

```{r grouping_loop, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

n <- params$n

for (i in n){
  cat('\n')
  cat("#  ", i, " \n")
  print(
    i
  )
  cat('\n')
  cat('\n')
}

```
````

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I want. A new title AND a new plot have to be generated each time printNewPlot is clicked. I expect the button to be clicked at least 4-5 times and a new title and a new graph to appear on the Rmd for each click.

Comment: So you want an RMD builder that stores each click's parameters and then prints across all of those stored parameters in one document?

Comment: Will you give me a chance to amend my answer?

Comment: @andandandand, please see the amended answer.

Comment: @Thanks! I'll check it on my computer when I get the chance. Note that the make_ring() function is from igraph. I corrected my question to include it..